# Non-interactive Rake task "db:initial_setup"

Tags: rake, canvas-lms

I'm trying to automate the installation of [canvas LMS](https://github.com/instructure/canvas-lms) which requires the execution of

```
bundle exec rake db:initial_setup
```

which asks for an admin email and password interactively

How do I pass those values in a non-interactive way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be done by setting the following environmental variables :

> CANVAS_LMS_ADMIN_EMAIL
>
> CANVAS_LMS_ADMIN_PASSWORD
>
> CANVAS_LMS_STATS_COLLECTION
>
> CANVAS_LMS_ACCOUNT_NAME

Answer (score 0):

I realize it's a late addition, but to clarify Eslam's answer, the details you're seeking are on the [Production Start](https://github.com/instructure/canvas-lms/wiki/Production-Start) page under the [Database Population](https://github.com/instructure/canvas-lms/wiki/Production-Start#database-population) heading.